# Button with emoji positioned differently than button with text

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons.

HTML:

```
<div style="position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0">
    <button class="top-button">
        
    </button>
    <button class="top-button">
        Text
    </button> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-button {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    min-width: 2rem;
    min-height: 2rem;
    background-color: rgba(180, 180, 180, 50%);
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px darkgray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0.1rem;
}
```

Live example: https://playcode.io/1629892

[image: Screenshot]

As you could see, the button with emoji located a little bit upper than then button with text. I would like make both buttons aligned. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a different line-height. You can add to the class .top-button

```
line-height: 100%;
```

That should fix it.

On the other side will I recommend you to use flex-box like in the following example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="top-button">
                
            </button>
      <button class="top-button">
        Text
      </button> 
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And for css:

```
.btn-group {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    /* Optional a gap between => gap: 10px; */
}

.top-button {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    min-width: 2rem;
    min-height: 2rem;
    background-color: rgba(180, 180, 180, 50%);
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px darkgray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0.1rem;
}
```